# tinyscrollbar does not appear

Tags: css, web, tinyscrollbar

I'm so confused, I want to make a sidebar with plugin tinyscrollbar, I want "height" of viewport is '100%' but if i change the css then the content is does not appear, can you give me another solution?

This a default code of tinyscrollbar but I change the  'height' of viewport:

```
#scrollbar1 { 
width: 520px; 
margin: 20px 0 10px; }
#scrollbar1 .viewport { 
width: 500px; 
height: 100%; 
overflow: hidden; 
position: relative; }
#scrollbar1 .overview {
height:100%;
list-style: none; 
position: absolute; 
left: 0; 
top: 0; 
padding: 0; 
margin: 0; }
#scrollbar1 .scrollbar{ 
background: transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-track-y.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
position: relative; 
background-position: 0 0; 
float: right; 
width: 15px;
height:100% }
#scrollbar1 .track { 
background: transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-trackend-y.png) no-repeat 0 100%; 
height: 100%;
width:13px; 
position: relative; 
padding: 0 1px; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb { 
background: transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-thumb-y.png) no-repeat 50% 100%; 
height: 20px; width: 25px; 
cursor: pointer; 
overflow: hidden; 
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: -5px; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb .end { 
background: transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-thumb-y.png) no-repeat 50% 0; 
overflow: hidden; 
height: 5px; 
width: 25px; }
#scrollbar1 .disable { 
display: none; }
.noSelect { 
user-select: none; 
-o-user-select: none; 
-moz-user-select: none; 
-khtml-user-select: none; 
-webkit-user-select: none; }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by setting the height of viewport to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it proportional (percent), you'll need a fixed value for it. Use jQuery or something similar to determine the actual height, then use it as a fixed pixel height value. This is the best I can advise. Also, you may need to react on window resizing.

Comment: Right now I'm using a mobile device so I can't give you any code examples; however, you can google it like "setting height with jquery" and "determine 100% height with jquery"... BUT, first of all you should try if fixed height really does the job. Maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: thanks sir..!

I've been browsing and already get the solution but when I try
changed into a 'fixed' position in css, then the scrollbars visible but the content is not visible..

Comment: Well, then maybe the scrollbar module has a problem :( Many times they work by adding an absolute div, maybe it's covering all your area to be scrolled and it's empty for some reason...  Honestly, I don't know. I'm sorry for not being able to give further help.